# Use AngularJS to make a spreadsheet (like) application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would make a webapp that works like a spreadsheet, that when you update one cell (input) all references are automatically updated.

How to achieve this in angular?

eg:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="TestController">
   <input ng-model="a1" /><input ng-model="b1" /><br />
   <input ng-model="a2" /><input ng-model="b2" />
</div>

function TestController($scope) {
   $scope.a1 = "";   
   $scope.a2 = "";   
   $scope.b1 = "";   
   $scope.b2 = $scope.a1 + $scope.a2;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/2622/

The problem is that B2 is evaluated the first time, but when a1 or a2 changes it doesn't automatically changes.

**The answers below are right**, but I'm looking for an **efficient way** to do it. Does exist any library for Angular that tackles this kind of "reactive programming"?

Comment: So `watch` for changes and update

Comment: can you not use an input and use `ng-bind-template` on a label?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$scope.$watch` to do something like

```
function TestController($scope) {
    $scope.a1 = "1";   
    $scope.a2 = "2";   
    $scope.b1 = "";   
    $scope.b2 = $scope.a1 + $scope.a2;
    $scope.b2_eval = function() {
            $scope.b2 = $scope.a1 + $scope.a2;
    }
    $scope.b2_deps = ['a1', 'a2'];
    $scope.b2_deps.forEach(function(dep) {
        $scope.$watch(dep, function() {
            $scope.b2_eval();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It works, but it's impraticable: every time I add a reference in a cell I have to repeat the formula for every watch function it depends on.. and maybe it's even wrong (what about loops?)

Comment: Well, this is for really simple cases. Excel for sure is not easy to implement :)
Updated my example with more automated way to update the values, but still you have to think of a good way to declare dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding watches you could just add an `ng-change` event to the input boxes and add a global update function to run when any value changes as in the updated example of your code below:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/declanmcd/u7xc175b/1/)

This update function could be as complex or simple as you want such as passing in a reference and only adding (or actioning) the input cells in the row or column you pass in.

You could also just add all the cells as an array and iterate through using an `ng-repeat`